# Choose different languages for each target within iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, project

I have an iOS project (current XCode) which is supporting 5 languages and have few targets in it. I would like to be able to select somehow languages per target (without removing them manually). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up creating two scripts. The same time I am adding changes from my US files to default en lproj (my US and GB differs a little).

One for removing unnecessary languages

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.backup ]; then
    echo "Last changes were not yet reverted."
else
    # move files from en-US to en
    cp -f en-US.lproj /* en.lproj */

    # remove from project file all occurences of unwanted languages
    cp ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.backup
    grep -v "en-GB.lproj" ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj > ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2; mv ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2 ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    grep -v "fr.lproj" ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj > ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2; mv ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2 ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    grep -v "it.lproj" ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj > ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2; mv ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2 ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    grep -v "sv.lproj" ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj > ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2; mv ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj2 ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

And second for getting back all language pack

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.backup ]; then
    mv ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.backup ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

1 - Create two language string files

[image]

2 - For each strings file, select the target you want to use the file and the languages available for that target

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1) Best way is add support any localization in one target. You can choose your any file and choose "Make Localized.." for add a folders:

```
en.lproj
de.lproj
```

2) If you don't want to do a 1st step, then you can just use one file, where is your localization texts. And add each at each target. Example:

**Texts_en.txt** added in **MyProject_en** target only
**Texts_de.txt** added in **MyProject_de** target only

**UPD:**

Or you can add a Preprocessor Macros for each target

```
LANG_ENG
LANG_GER
```

And in your code you must use thems

Comment: The problem is that languages supported are general for Project - and what I want is narrow this per target. E.g. if you have stacked strings files you could choose which target they belong to but its save for all those files (and not specific language to specific target)
What I need to do now I think is go to each localized files stacked in XCode and deselect language in localization (at file inspector) for certain target I am building

Comment: I have them and use but I don't know they could help me here. Strings file doesn't support preprocessor macros (as far as I know) and even if they would then problem stays because app would think that each language is supported.

What else could help here is creating some scripts that will (re)move some localization files before building target - but I have to check how XCode will behieve (having languages but now having .lproj files)